# Unable to install bundler with gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using ruby 2.6.5 and I try to install bundler -v 2.2.27 gem according to documentation using this command:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.27 --default
```

And this is the output I get:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.27 --default
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.27 as a default gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/specifications/gems/bundler-2.2.27
```

It says it installed the gem but errors out at the same time :)
When I check current version of bundler I get this output

```
gem info bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.32, 2.2.27, 2.2.24, 2.1.4)
    Authors: André Arko, Samuel Giddins, Colby Swandale, Hiroshi
    Shibata, David Rodríguez, Grey Baker, Stephanie Morillo, Chris
    Morris, James Wen, Tim Moore, André Medeiros, Jessica Lynn Suttles,
    Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Homepage: https://bundler.io
    License: MIT
    Installed at (2.2.32): /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
                 (2.2.27, default): /Users/jedrek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (2.2.24): /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
                 (2.1.4): /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
```

As you can see it says that bundler -v 2.2.27 is installed.
When I try to install dependencies in my project I get this error:

```
bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 2.2.27)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.4)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 2.2.27)' in any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation
```

Listing current bundler version locally shows this output

```
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.32, default: 2.2.27, 2.2.24, 2.1.4)
bundler-audit (0.7.0.1, 0.6.1)
capistrano-bundler (2.0.1, 1.3.0)
```

I am so confused. Is this is a bug?
I am using rubygems 3.2.27

```
gem --version
3.2.27
```

**UPDATE**

I tried upgrading rubygems to 3.2.32 and have the same issue.

Comment: "bundle install
Resolving dependencies..." do you have `gem "bunlder"` in your Gemfile?

Comment: Delete `bundler` from the `Gemfile`. `bundler` is a library to *manage* your dependencies. `bundler` is not, it itself, a dependency of the project.

Comment: I don't have bundler in Gemfile, why would I have one? You don't put bundler in Gemfile, it is, however, in my .gemscpec file `spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 2.2.27"`

Comment: What does `bundle --version` say?

Comment: `Bundler version 2.1.4`